# custom contact form not working with magento installation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to implement [this Contact form](http://www.kontaktformular.com/en/demo/style3-security-question/contact.php) from kontaktformular.com inside a separate folder (named "custom-contact-form") on my Magento root directory.

Eg: mywebsite.com/custom-contact-form

Now, kontaktformular.com gives you whole package with html, php and css files to make and run your custom contact form. [Here is the package.](http://www.kontaktformular.com/en/dlcounter-neu/count.php?id=10)

One of the files that they give out is test.php to send a test mail to a given email address to see if everything works all right or not. This file is has a pretty simple php script to send an email to a secific email address. Now, it doesn't work! And I can't figure out why? Is it because of some kind of PHP conflict with magento installation?

Infact, I have tried many other simple contact form scripts and none of them seem to work.
I want to know the reason causing it not to work. Also, is there a way to add a custom contact form in magento WITHOUT creating a new extenshion?

Comment: try running simple php mail function on a test file and see if the mail is configured correctly on your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh, why do you want use that contact form?

the magento connect has this very nice webforms extension.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webforms-community-edition.html